# Is there any reason why my code isnt grouping my dataframe by Country?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, multiple-columns

I'm using some trade import information and have 2 dataframes - Eur countries and Non Eur countries. One of them is pre-grouped by Commodity and one is grouped by Country name. I want them to both be grouped by country so i can sum the total import amount. Here is my code:

```
#Import csv of data on these materials
ironDirtyEur=read_csv('EURIMPORTS.csv', skipinitialspace=True)
ironDirtyNonEur=read_csv('NONEURIMPORTS.csv', skipinitialspace=True)

#Will remove extra characters from columns like so:
ironDirtyEur['Commodity']=ironDirtyEur['Commodity'].str.rstrip(' ')
ironDirtyNonEur['Commodity']=ironDirtyNonEur['Commodity'].str.rstrip(' ')

#Now need to remove unwanted columns
headings=['Reporter','Commodity',TRADE_VALUE]
ironDirtyEurTrimmed=ironDirtyEur[headings]
ironDirtyNonEurTrimmed=ironDirtyNonEur[headings]

#Also is beneficial to replace reporter with Country Name so we can link the dataframes later
ironDirtyEurTrimmed=ironDirtyEurTrimmed.rename(columns={'Reporter':'Country Name'})
ironDirtyNonEurTrimmed=ironDirtyNonEurTrimmed.rename(columns={'Reporter':'Country Name'})


#We need to group these by country and work out the total amount of imports of these materials per country
eurImportsGrouped=ironDirtyEurTrimmed.groupby(COUNTRY)
#The Above doesn't change the fact that they're grouped by commodity


nonEurImportsGrouped=ironDirtyNonEurTrimmed.groupby(COUNTRY)
nonEurImportsGrouped.get_group('Rice')
```

The final line states a KeyError for Rice even though i copied it in directly from the (backup) CSV file which makes me believe there is an issue in my code somewhere.

Am i missing something obvious?

Comment: That is not what groupby is made for. It is intended to compute aggregated values on groups, as does the SQL clause GROUP BY. What you want is probably `sort_values`.

Comment: Ah okay, do you know why when I use the get_group function for Rice (one of the commodities listed) is doesn't return it?

Comment: `.groupby(COUNTRY)` - `COUNTRY` is supposed to be a column name - is it? Is it the correct column? if you iterate over the groups and print the keys do you see what you expect? - `for key,grp in nonEurImportsGrouped: print(key)`